# Editing com.apple.atrun.plist on El Capitan

Tags: macos, permission, launchd, sip

I am running El Capitan on several computers and would like to be able to use at to run scheduled jobs in the background.  Enabling at requires editing /System/Library/LaunchDaemon/com.apple.atrun.plist.  Any way I have tried to do this, I have run into a permissions problem: using sudo, logging in as root or trying to change the permissions from the file information panel all result on a permissions error of some sort.

I have tried:

1. `sudo vi /System/Library/LaunchDaemon/com.apple.atrun.plist` and not been able to save the edited file.
2. Copying to file, editing it and copying back - I am not allowed to copy back using sudo.
3. Using Xcode to edited the fiel through a GUI, cannot save.
4. using Property List Editor, cannot save, even logged in as root.
5. Changing owner, group is not allowed, even using sudo or logged in a root.
6. Changing permissions of all the subdirectories in the tree above (System, System/Library, etc.) used sudo, also tried changed disk permissions.
7. Run disk utility.

There must be some way of doing this, please advise.

Answer (score 3):

The file *com.apple.atrun.plist* is protected by System Integrity Protection.

So boot to the Recovery HD partition (hold down <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> while restarting), disable SIP and modify the item:

1. In the menubar open Utilities->Terminal
2. Enter `csrutil disable`
3. Reboot to your main volume and edit the file
4. Reboot into the Recovery Partition again
5. Enable SIP again `csrutil enable`
6. Reboot to your main volume

Comment: The answer given by @klanomath is correct, but further action is required in Mojave (10.14).  SIP has been taken a step further to Transparency Consent and Control (TCC).  In short, you must explicitly grant full disk access to atrun:

 1. Go to System Preferences->Security & Privacy.
 2. Select Full Disk Access and click the padlock icon to make changes.
 3. Click the `+` icon below the box on the right and add `atrun`.

The path to `atrun` is `/usr/libexec/atrun`.  Select your root drive (probably something like 'Macintosh HD') and press `Command`+`Shift`+`.`.

Answer (score 1):

Using 10.11.6 (El Capitan) I was able to get `atrun` to run following the instructions found in the article "[Using at for command scheduling under Mac OS X](https://developercoach.com/using-at-for-command-scheduling-under-mac-os-x/)".

To enable `atrun`, execute,

`sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.atrun.plist`

To disable `atrun`, execute,

`sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.atrun.plist`

The article has additional useful information about `atrun` and at commands.